# Deterministic shifts

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

We consider (topological) dynamical systems $(\Omega, S)$, where $S$ is the shift $(Sx)_n=x_{n+1}$, and $\Omega\subset[0,1]^{\mathbb Z}$ is a compact, shift invariant subspace. I call such a system $(\Omega, S)$ *deterministic* if $x_n=y_n$ for all $n<0$ implies that $x=y$ for any two points $x,y\in\Omega$. (Of course, this is a non-standard use of the term.)

We now consider conjugacies between shifts, that is, homeomorphisms $\varphi: \Omega_1\to\Omega_2$ such that $\varphi S= S\varphi$.
Determinism in the above sense is a property of the space $\Omega$, not of the dynamical system, and it is not invariant under conjugacy: for an easy example, take the full shift on two symbols $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb Z}$. This is clearly non-deterministic, but we can map $f:\Omega\to C\subset[0,1]$ homeomorphically and then define $\varphi(x)$ as the sequence whose $n$th entry is $f(S^nx)$. Then $\varphi$ is an isomorphism (of dynamical systems) onto a deterministic system; in fact, in this new realization, $x$ is already determined by $x_0$.

Two questions: (1) Are there systems of this type that are *not* isomorphic to a deterministic shift? Put differently, is the full shift on $[0,1]^{\mathbb Z}$ isomorphic to a deterministic shift?

(2) Can one say non-trivial things about systems that have *only* deterministic realizations in this sense? (For example, distal systems have this property, but that's quite obvious.)

Comment: There are a few strange points in your question, possibly misprints (e.g. in the conjugacy, I guess there is a $S_1$ and a $S_2$). With regard to question (1), why can't you use the same construction as in the previous §, taking $\Omega_2=\Omega_1^\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Benoit: All my $\Omega$'s are by assumption contained in $[0,1]^{\mathbb Z}$ (the question disappears otherwise, as you pointed out). That probably answers the first question, too: all shifts are restrictions of the one on that space.

Comment: The property that you call "deterministic shift" seems to be a stronger variant of having zero entropy. In particular, any system with positive entropy cannot be isomorphic to a deterministic shift.

Comment: Moreover, to be isomorphic to a subshift of the shift $[0,1]^\mathbb{Z}$ is a property of coding of your system, which seems to me to be totally independent of your property of "determinism". This "determinism" property can be expressed in terms of stable/unstable manifolds, without referring to any coding: if $W^u(v)=W^u(w)$ then $W^s(v)=W^s(w)$ which is an extremely rigid property.

Comment: @Barbara: The example I gave (Bernoulli shift) has positive entropy. I'm pretty sure in fact that there are subshifts with infinite entropy that can be realized as deterministic shifts.

Comment: To any subshift of $\Omega\subset[0,1]^\mathbb Z$ we can attach a Volume measure defined as 
$$Vol(\Omega)=Vol(\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty}\pi_{[1,n]}(\Omega))$$
where $\pi_{[1,n]}$ is the projection to $n$ consecutive coordinates. This is not invariant under conjugacy. I am not sure, is it possibly the fact that it being non-zero is? This also seems to be related to the question of ``determinism'' is the sense that if the $Vol(\Omega)$ is non-zero then it is not a deterministic subshift. Most of what I have said is speculation, please take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Nishant: I think the notion you're trying to catch is "mean dimension", as analyzed by Lindenstrauss-Weiss. Their work is related to this question, basically, because a system is deterministic in my sense precisely if it can be embedded in $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$. I believe the L-W methods, slightly adapted, show that there is a $c>0$ such that any shift with mean dim $<c$ is deterministic.

Comment: This is very interesting. I was not familiar with this work and will look it over. Thank you.